# Plotting x and y values with result as color / heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Basically I have some x and y values. Each set of x and y values have a given value that corresponds to them. I am not sure a general `seaborn` heatmap would suffice when wanting to do that (I might be mistaken), so what to do ?

I would like it to look something like this (including bins, so that it's a more "smooth" colored surface, and not just a lot of different colored dots all around):

[image]

EDIT:
So I'll try to explain better.

Let's say I have something like this:

```
import numpy as np 

nx = 3
ny = 5

x = np.linspace(0.1, 1, nx) 
y = np.linspace(1, 11, ny) 

x_bc = x[:, np.newaxis]
y_bc = y[np.newaxis, :]
z = x_bc * y_bc
```

The output of `z` is then every combination of `x` and `y`, i.e.:

```
[[  0.1     0.35    0.6     0.85    1.1  ]
[  0.55    1.925   3.3     4.675   6.05 ]
[  1.      3.5     6.      8.5    11.   ]]
```

So in this case I have 3x5 `z`-values, i.e. what should be the colors in the plot, and those values come from two lists (`x` and `y`) that has length 3 and 5 respectively. That is pretty much what I would like to plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lines look like contours. In order to draw them and have the spaces between them filled with colors you can use [`contourf`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html#matplotlib-pyplot-contourf).

In order to make this work I had to transpose `z` so that the number of columns match the size of `x` and the number of rows match the size of `y`.

```
nx = 3
ny = 5

x = np.linspace(0.1, 1, nx) 
y = np.linspace(1, 11, ny) 

x_bc = x[:, np.newaxis]
y_bc = y[np.newaxis, :]
z = x_bc * y_bc

plt.contourf(x, y, z.T)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Comment: @DenverDang I think it is because I had to change your data creation code to fix a `NameError`. Now you have changed it but it raises `ValueError`. Fix your code and I will fix the answer.

Comment: Ah yes, typo from me. It has been fixed. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something you may be able to pull off with a [kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html?highlight=kdeplot#seaborn.kdeplot) starting like this:

```
 ax = sns.kdeplot(x, y, shade=True)
```

Comment: But as far as I can see, there is no way to "tell it" about your resulting values, i.e. the ones that should determine the color, if this is just a `(x, y)` plot, right ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html). If your x, y coordinates are defined over a uniform grid, then `contourf` should do the trick; otherwise, `tricontourf` will triangulate and interpolate the data for you. Have a look at [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/irregulardatagrid.html) example:

[image]

Comment: But unfortunately, I'm not using a uniform grid. The list of x and y values has different lengths. And I get an error for exactly that not being the case it seems.

Comment: Every point you plot in a 2D space requires one `x` coordinate and one `y` coordinate, so it is mathematically impossible to plot using coordinate lists of different lengths; they MUST have the same length, and that doesn't depend on your code implementation. Can you provide a short code snippet with some of your data and what you have tried so far? We might be able to get a better idea of what you are trying to do from that.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying. I have tried to explain it better in my OP now. Hopefully that will give a better overview of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ah yes, your question is much clearer now. When you multiply `x` and `y` using `np.newaxis`, you are essentially defining a uniform grid of (x, y) coordinates - hence you could use `contourf`. Glad to see you got it sorted :)